# finalfit obtaining p-value column for continuous dependent variable

Tags: r

I'm using `finalfit` which is great for outputting model fits etc but in the simpler case below I only have a continuous outcome as my dependent variable. 1) I was wondering is there a way that specifying `p = TRUE` can obtain a p-value across the label values as you can if you have a factor variable? 2) how can I specify a different type of test. The vignette [here](https://finalfit.org/articles/all_tables_examples.html) say its uses "Kruskal-Wallis/Mann-Whitney for continuous", what if we wanted a different test, how would we specify this? 3) similarly when you have a continuous variable, is there a way to add counts and percentage of the explanatory variables after levels columns?

Example code which produces a p-value column when dependent variable is a factor:

```
library(finalfit)
explanatory = c("age", "age.factor", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor")
dependent = "perfor.factor"
t <- colon_s %>%
    summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE) 
t

#         label      levels          No         Yes     p
# 1 Age (years)   Mean (SD) 59.8 (11.9) 58.4 (13.3) 0.578
# 2         Age   <40 years   68 (97.1)     2 (2.9) 1.000
# 3             40-59 years  334 (97.1)    10 (2.9)      
# 4               60+ years  500 (97.1)    15 (2.9)      
# 7         Sex      Female  432 (97.1)    13 (2.9) 0.979
# 8                    Male  470 (97.1)    14 (2.9)      
# 5 Obstruction          No  715 (97.7)    17 (2.3) 0.018
# 6                     Yes  166 (94.3)    10 (5.7)
```

Now I would like to have a p-value column in the case of a continuous variable:

```
explanatory = c("age.factor", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor", "perfor.factor")
dependent = "time"
## Crosstable
table_1 <- colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE) 
table_1

#         label      levels      Mean (sd)
# 1         Age   <40 years 1544.3 (867.6)
# 2             40-59 years 1769.4 (861.1)
# 3               60+ years 1620.6 (875.3)
# 4         Sex      Female 1674.2 (884.6)
# 5                    Male 1666.0 (861.4)
# 6 Obstruction          No 1700.0 (852.4)
# 7                     Yes 1515.6 (933.6)
# 8 Perforation          No 1671.2 (873.1)
# 9                     Yes 1627.6 (851.8)
```

The `p = TRUE` doesn't work in this case, the p-value column I was thinking would run a test say, comparing the mean/median value of `time` between `Sex` depending on type of test suggested. Also after the levels column how can I add count and proportion column, e.g. female `445 (47 %)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalfit 1.0.0 is in preview phase and available to install from Github below. I'd appreciate if you could have a look and make sure it is doing what it should. There have been quite a few re-writes/improvements so there may be bugs.

**Install**

```
remotes::install_github('ewenharrison/finalfit')
```

**Hypothesis test with continuous dependent**

```
explanatory = c("age.factor", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor", "perfor.factor")
dependent = "time"
colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE) 

       label      levels      unit          value     p
 Age (years) [18.0,85.0] Mean (sd) 1670.0 (872.1) 0.543
         Age   <40 years Mean (sd) 1544.3 (867.6) 0.023
             40-59 years Mean (sd) 1769.4 (861.1)      
               60+ years Mean (sd) 1620.6 (875.3)      
         Sex      Female Mean (sd) 1674.2 (884.6) 0.886
                    Male Mean (sd) 1666.0 (861.4)      
 Obstruction          No Mean (sd) 1700.0 (852.4) 0.012
                     Yes Mean (sd) 1515.6 (933.6)      
 Perforation          No Mean (sd) 1671.2 (873.1) 0.798
                     Yes Mean (sd) 1627.6 (851.8)
```

Continuous vs continuous is the Pearson coefficient p-value (probably of limited use). 
Continuous vs. categorical is analysis of variance by default, `p_cont_para = "aov"`.  Where only two-level explanatory factors exist, this can be changed to `p_cont_para = "t.test"` for a Welch t-test.

**Non parametric options**

Make all summaries median (iqr) and use Spearman's rank for cont/cont and Kruskal Wallis for cont/cat.

```
colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE,
    cont = "median") 

       label      levels         unit     value     p
 Age (years) [18.0,85.0] Median (IQR) 2.0 (4.0) 0.001
         Age   <40 years Median (IQR) 3.0 (5.0) 0.027
             40-59 years Median (IQR) 3.0 (4.0)      
               60+ years Median (IQR) 2.0 (3.0)      
         Sex      Female Median (IQR) 3.0 (4.0) 0.777
                    Male Median (IQR) 2.0 (3.0)      
 Obstruction          No Median (IQR) 2.0 (4.0) 0.774
                     Yes Median (IQR) 3.0 (3.0)      
 Perforation          No Median (IQR) 2.0 (4.0) 0.125
                     Yes Median (IQR) 3.0 (2.0)
```

Interquartile range, rather than Q3-Q1.

```
colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE, 
    cont = "median", cont_range = TRUE) 
       label      levels         unit            value     p
 Age (years) [18.0,85.0] Median (IQR) 2.0 (1.0 to 5.0) 0.001
         Age   <40 years Median (IQR) 3.0 (2.0 to 7.0) 0.027
             40-59 years Median (IQR) 3.0 (1.0 to 5.0)      
               60+ years Median (IQR) 2.0 (1.0 to 4.0)      
         Sex      Female Median (IQR) 3.0 (1.0 to 5.0) 0.777
                    Male Median (IQR) 2.0 (1.0 to 4.0)      
 Obstruction          No Median (IQR) 2.0 (1.0 to 5.0) 0.774
                     Yes Median (IQR) 3.0 (1.0 to 4.0)      
 Perforation          No Median (IQR) 2.0 (1.0 to 5.0) 0.125
                     Yes Median (IQR) 3.0 (2.0 to 4.0)
```

Specify which variables to make non-parametric

```
colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE, 
    cont_nonpara = c(1, 3, 5)) 

       label      levels         unit     value     p
 Age (years) [18.0,85.0] Median (IQR) 2.0 (4.0) 0.001
         Age   <40 years    Mean (sd) 4.7 (4.5) 0.034
             40-59 years    Mean (sd) 3.6 (3.3)      
               60+ years    Mean (sd) 3.6 (3.6)      
         Sex      Female Median (IQR) 3.0 (4.0) 0.777
                    Male Median (IQR) 2.0 (3.0)      
 Obstruction          No    Mean (sd) 3.7 (3.7) 0.435
                     Yes    Mean (sd) 3.5 (3.2)      
 Perforation          No Median (IQR) 2.0 (4.0) 0.125
                     Yes Median (IQR) 3.0 (2.0)
```

**Add counts and missing data**

This is surprisingly tricky to get straight, particularly when there are missing data in the dependent and explanatory variables. Here are the current thoughts.

```
explanatory = c("age", "nodes", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor")
dependent = "time"

# Change 29 rows in variable time to missing
colon_s[1:29, "time"] = NA

colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE, 
    total_col = TRUE, add_row_totals = TRUE) 

       label Total N Missing N      levels      unit          value       Total      p
 Age (years)     900         0 [18.0,85.0] Mean (sd) 1663.6 (860.2) 900 (100.0)  0.766
       nodes     882        18  [0.0,33.0] Mean (sd) 1663.6 (860.2) 882 (100.0) <0.001
         Sex     900         0      Female Mean (sd) 1674.6 (873.8)  432 (48.0)  0.712
                                      Male Mean (sd) 1653.4 (848.3)  468 (52.0)       
 Obstruction     881        19          No Mean (sd) 1687.7 (840.8)  713 (80.9)  0.039
                                       Yes Mean (sd) 1535.8 (924.0)  168 (19.1)
```

The `Total N` column (`add_row_totals = TRUE`) is the total number of values for that explanatory variable. Here the data frame is 929 long but with 29 missings in the dependent. `Missing N` is the missing from that variable only, not including the dependent missing. The `Total` column (`total_col = TRUE`) is historical and kept with that name and argument for compatibility. But that shows the proportion split across factors.

**Showing missing data**

The following makes missing data in the explanatory factors explicit, but doesn't pass the missing data to the hypothesis test.

```
colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE, 
    total_col = TRUE, add_row_totals = TRUE,
    na_include = TRUE) 

       label Total N Missing N      levels      unit          value       Total      p
 Age (years)     900         0 [18.0,85.0] Mean (sd) 1663.6 (860.2) 900 (100.0)  0.766
       nodes     882        18  [0.0,33.0] Mean (sd) 1663.6 (860.2) 882 (100.0) <0.001
         Sex     900         0      Female Mean (sd) 1674.6 (873.8)  432 (48.0)  0.712
                                      Male Mean (sd) 1653.4 (848.3)  468 (52.0)       
 Obstruction     881        19          No Mean (sd) 1687.7 (840.8)  713 (79.2)  0.039
                                       Yes Mean (sd) 1535.8 (924.0)  168 (18.7)       
                                 (Missing) Mean (sd) 1890.4 (916.5)    19 (2.1)
```

**Passing missing data levels to hypothesis test**

```
colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE, 
    total_col = TRUE, add_row_totals = TRUE,
    na_include = TRUE, na_to_p = TRUE) 

       label Total N Missing N      levels      unit          value       Total      p
 Age (years)     900         0 [18.0,85.0] Mean (sd) 1663.6 (860.2) 900 (100.0)  0.766
       nodes     882        18  [0.0,33.0] Mean (sd) 1663.6 (860.2) 882 (100.0) <0.001
         Sex     900         0      Female Mean (sd) 1674.6 (873.8)  432 (48.0)  0.712
                                      Male Mean (sd) 1653.4 (848.3)  468 (52.0)       
 Obstruction     881        19          No Mean (sd) 1687.7 (840.8)  713 (79.2)  0.061
                                       Yes Mean (sd) 1535.8 (924.0)  168 (18.7)       
                                 (Missing) Mean (sd) 1890.4 (916.5)    19 (2.1)
```

**Complete case analysis**

This is quite useful when progressing to linear models. What data are actually included in the model after row-wise deletion.

```
colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, p = TRUE, 
    total_col = TRUE, add_row_totals = TRUE,
    na_complete_case = TRUE) 


       label Total N Missing N      levels      unit          value       Total      p
 Age (years)     863        37 [18.0,85.0] Mean (sd) 1664.2 (856.1) 863 (100.0)  0.766
       nodes     863        37  [0.0,33.0] Mean (sd) 1664.2 (856.1) 863 (100.0) <0.001
         Sex     863        37      Female Mean (sd) 1672.6 (869.5)  414 (48.0)  0.712
                                      Male Mean (sd) 1656.5 (844.4)  449 (52.0)       
 Obstruction     863        37          No Mean (sd) 1691.3 (837.9)  699 (81.0)  0.039
                                       Yes Mean (sd) 1548.7 (923.3)  164 (19.0)
```

Details here: https://finalfit.org/
Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: this looks like exactly what I was after (I wont be testing it straight away but any issues, I'll let you know), great answer

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way to use `finalfit` to do a simpler table 1, for example one with just general %'s and means of the whole dataset. Using your example, you could do this `colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, total_col = TRUE) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-unit, -value)` but this gets the `age.factor` wrong (although the others are correct). Obviously you could play around with different merges but I feel the package might already do this although I cant seem to find it? Basic I want to drop `dependent` in the function call. Thanks

Comment: New questions are best not put in comments. Just drop dependent from function call. `colon_s %>% summary_factorlist(explanatory = explanatory)`

Answer (score 1):

All of these features will be available in Finalfit 1.0.0 which will be released shortly. Maybe before Christmas. Thanks for your interest.